Kendo MVC Grid controll cannot call to an Async Task action method in the controller
In my cshtml view, I have this kendo mvc grid control below.
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModel>()
  .Name("mygriddata")
  .Columns(column =>
  {
      column.Bound(model => model.MyData).Title("No.").....
  })
    .Pageable(x => x.PageSizes(true).ButtonCount(3).Responsive(false))
    .AutoBind(false)
    .Filterable()
    .Sortable(x => x.Enabled(true))
    .Resizable(resizable => resizable.Columns(true))
    .Scrollable(x => x.Height("auto"))
    .PersistSelection()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 50vh; margin-left:10px", @class = "form-group" })
    .NoRecords()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(item => item.ID);
        })
        .Read(read => read.Action("MyActionMethod", "MyController"))
    )
)

In in my controller, I have this async task action method.
public async Task<JsonResult> MyActionMethod([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var data = await _service.GetData();
     var model = data.Select((item, index) => new MyModel
                    {
                        MyData = ......
                    });

    return new JsonResult { Data = model.ToDataSourceResultAsync(request), MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}

Then, when the grid control loads data, I got this error. How to set up the Kendo mvc grid control in this case?
Message: The asynchronous action method 'MyActionMethod' returns a Task, which cannot be executed synchronously.


I see you are awaiting the call to the service, but not the ToDataSourceResultAsync() call. I'd guess that's why the error occurs.

I tried using ToDataSourceResult() too, and still getting the error. I have no idea how to use the kendo grid control in this context. :|

Does it work when you make the controller method synchronous? Also, in the examples I've seen, the async grid controller methods use ActionResult instead of JsonResult, as shown here: https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/knowledge-base/grid-add-asynchronous-calls-to-action-methods

Yes, It works properly with synchronous. I then want to enhance it to work with async and I get the problem. I am now looking at your mentioned docs. thanks
